# Erroneous sym type

Tags: java, methods, call

I've searched through a few different posts but haven't found the exact issue I am having. I feel like what I am missing should be very obvious but for some reason can't quite pin it down have been playing with everything but cant quite get it. If anyone can give me a hand it would be greatly appreciated. The program is meant to pull house information from a text file and output it. the JMUnit7 file was given to us by the instructor. The JMUnit7House file is my work. Thanks in advance.

```
  package jmunit7;
  import java.util.Scanner; 
  import java.io.File; 
  import java.io.IOException;
  /**
  *
  * @author Xephus
  */
 public class JMUnit7 {

  /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  * @throws java.lang.Exception
  */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner stdInFile = new Scanner(new
    File("JMUnit7House.txt"));
    JMUnit7House house1, house2; //New houses

    //Create house 1 using default constructor
    house1 = new JMUnit7House();
    house1.print(); //print house 1 with default values

    String street, city, state, zipCode;
    int number;

    System.out.println("Importing Number.");
    number = stdInFile.nextInt();
    stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing Street.");
    street = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing City.");
    city = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing State.");
    state = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing ZipCode.");
    zipCode = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    //use method call chaining to set values
    //and print results for house 1
    house1.setNumber(number).setStreet(street)
           .setCity(city).setState(state)
            .setZipCode(zipCode).print();

    System.out.println("Importing Number.");
    number = stdInFile.nextInt();
    stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing Street.");
    street = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing City.");
    city = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing State.");
    state = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Importing ZipCode.");
    zipCode = stdInFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    //create house 2 using 5 parameter constructor
    house2 = new JMUnit7House(number,
    street, city, state, zipCode);
    //print house 2
    house2.print();
    }
}
```

My code is as follows im getting and erroneous sym type error which is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: .setCity.setState.setZipCode.print at jmunit7.JMUnit7.main(JMUnit7.java:49) 49 is the house1.setNumber line.

```
 public class JMUnit7House {
 private int number; 
 private String street; 
 private String city; 
 private String state; 
 private String zipCode; 

 public JMUnit7House()
 {
    number = 0; 
    street = "No Street"; 
    city = "No City"; 
    state= "No State"; 
    zipCode = "No Zip Code"; 
   }
   //intializes house with arguments
   public JMUnit7House(int number, String street, String city, String state,              String zipCode)
   {
   this.number = number; 
   this.street = street; 
   this.city = city; 
   this.state = state; 
   this.zipCode = zipCode; 
   }
   public int setNumber(int number)
  {
   return number; 
  }
 public String setStreet(String street)
 {
   return street; 
 }
 public String setCity(String city)
 {
   return city; 
 }
 public String setState(String state)
 {
   return state; 
 }
 public String setZipCode(String zipCode)
 {
   return zipCode; 
 }

  //function to print
  public void print()
 {
    String info=String.format("House: %d\n", number); 
    info += String.format("Street: %s\n", street); 
    info += String.format("City: %s\n", city); 
    info += String.format("State: %s\n", state); 
    info += String.format("Zip: %s\n", zipCode);
    System.out.println(info);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using an IDE, clean all code errors and rebuild the project

Comment: The code error at that line on IDE is int cannot be dereferanced.

Comment: at which line in the code exactly?

Comment: house1.setNumber(number).setStreet(street)
           .setCity(city).setState(state)
            .setZipCode(zipCode).print();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I see the problem. In the below:

```
 house1.setNumber(number).setStreet(street)
           .setCity(city).setState(state)
            .setZipCode(zipCode).print();
```

Since, `setNumber()` returns a `int` and you're calling `setStreet()` on that, it won't work.

If you want to make calls in the above fashion return `this` object instead in the required methods.
For e.g.:

```
public int setNumber(int number)
  {
   //do something
   return number; 
  }
```

will become

```
public JMUnit7House setNumber(int number)
  {
   //do something
   return this; 
  }
```

Comment: separate issue for some reason its printing the first house as a blank house rather than assigning them variable from the .txt file the second house is displaying as expected.